Android AudioVideo Framework can not read metadata correctly
I've been trying to open *.mp4 media file on specific Android devices. Once I open it MediaFormat data has undefined language on audio tracks. If I then upload same app on different device, it decodes it correctly.
As of now, I tried MediaPlayer, MediaMetadataRetriever and MediaExtractor API's. Same issue is reproducible with C++ native code using AMediaExtractor API.
Example:
        val me = MediaExtractor()
        val fis = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mp4)
        me.setDataSource(fis.fileDescriptor, fis.startOffset, fis.length)
        val format = me.getTrackFormat(1)
        val language = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_LANGUAGE)

On Android 9 Razer Phone 2 this would return undefined, while any other of devices it works correctly and returns actual language info.
I've also reproduced same issue on Android 8.1.0 Asus Rog Phone
MIME for same track is audio/mp4a-latm. I've tried *.m4a audio file, but it has same issue.
Decoder on faulty devices seems to be OMX.google.aac, but I've found other devices with this decoder that work just fine.



MediaFormat data
Good Device (Galaxy 21 Plus)
Bad Device (Razer Phone 2)




max-bitrate
96000
96000


isDMCMMExtractor
1
1


sample-rate
48000
48000


track-id
2
2


mime
audio/mp4a-latm
audio/mp4a-latm


profile
2
Field Missing


bitrate
96000
96000


language
dan
und


aac-profile
2
2


track-fourcc
-1
Field Missing


encoder-delay
2112
Field Missing


durationUs
725333
725333


channel-count
2
2


bits-per-sample
16
16


encoder-padding
705
Field Missing


max-input-size
524308
65538


csd-0
[17, -112]
[17, -112]



File used is generated using FFMPEG CLI and has 8 audio tracks, but I've also extracted audio from it and used to test with same issue

Razer Phone 2 is a relatively old device (released in 2018). And I don't have one to verify the hypothesis.
According to AOSP there was a change made in November 2018 to use AMediaFormat in MPEG4Extractor.cpp.
Specifically, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_LANGUAGE (string value "language") is used instead of kKeyMediaLanguage (string value "lang").
So I suspect that Razer Phone 2 stores the language in the media format map under the key "lang", but you are looking for "language".

I'm currently using MediaFormat.KEY_LANGUAGE with Kotlin to get this info before implementing it in C++ framework.
MediaFormat.KEY_LANGUAGE on both RazerPhone2 and others return "language"
Just to be sure I've tried:
    `val language = me.getTrackFormat(1).getString("language")`
    `val lang = me.getTrackFormat(1).getString("lang")`

but language is just empty string and lang variable is null

Did you try to log getTrackFormat(1).toString()? It should print all the key-value pairs.

Yeah, it outputs {sample-rate=48000, track-id=2, file-format=video/mp4, durationUs=725333, aac-format-adif=0, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, channel-count=2, bitrate=10534, language=, aac-profile=2, max-input-size=65538, csd-0=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=2 cap=2]}

@dev.bmax Is it also possible that getTrackFormat in the newer SDK is always only looking for language= instead of lang=? At this point the OP might have to test that same get command whilst testing on an older Android version. Maybe even an emulator could confirm if testing various Android versions (not devices) will matter to show the correct language setting...

Same issue is reported on Android 12 Fairphone 4, so I'd think it would have something to do with codexes rather then android version directly. Furthermore ExoPlayer - New Google Product for media playing straight up reimplements decoding from ground up. It works as intended on the same files.

Metadata is read by a media extractor (a different component from a codec). You can list the available extractors using: adb shell dumpsys media.extractor. The problem could be either in a custom extractor installed on the device by the manufacturer or it can be a bug while the result is being returned to the app.
